# Call a function from phtml in another phtml

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a function `funcA()` defined in the script tag of `A.phtml`, I want to call and use this function in another `B.phtml` script tag instead of defining it again in `B.html`. Any ideas please?

Comment: create a comman js for that and include it in both pages